# Creating a new column based on data from an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

Consider a system to track repairs. I have a table with customer data and a common id key. I have a second table with a column to show which type of repair part was used on each id key and how many were used. Their definitions are below:

```
order_information
order_id  |  cust_last_name
465          Smith
899          Williams
512          Johnson
345          Fenton
122          Bowles
944          Cooper

parts_usage
order_id  |  part_type  |  part_quantity
465          Part 1        5
465          Part 2        4
899          Part 1        2
899          Part 2        8
899          Part 3        6
512          Part 3        1
345          Part 2        4
345          Part 3        5
122          Part 2        3
944          Part 1        2
```

I'd like to run a query for reporting that will return the part's pieces broken out like so:

```
order_id  |  Part 1  |  Part 2  |  Part 3  |  Total
465          5          4                     9
899          2          8          6          16
512                                1          1
345                     4          5          9
122                     3                     3
944          2                                2
```

Is it possible to do this with a query so that my reports can show how many of each part was used on each repair ticket?

As you can see, each `order_id` can have multiple part types and unique quantities. I want to break the different part types (I have 3 total) into 3 separate columns with their totals listed by `order_id`.

Comment: What you need is to Pivot your table. For example SQL Server has Pivot command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What RDBMS are you using. SQL is just a language used by many database systems. The solution you are looking for is likely to be vendor specific.

Comment: If you know you only have three parts and they are the same then cross tab of style `sum(case when part_type='part 1' then part_quantity end) as Part1` should work - otherwise a more sophisticated solution that is likely to be vendor specific as @GarethD states.

Comment: My RDBMS is Microsoft SQL Server. Thanks, Yuriy, PIVOT seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Still reading, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select order_id, [Part 1], [Part 2], [Part 3], Total
from 
(
  select oi.order_id
    , part_type
    , part_quantity
    , Total = sum(part_quantity) over (partition by oi.order_id)
  from order_information oi
    inner join parts_usage pu on oi.order_id = pu.order_id
) as parts
pivot 
(
  sum(part_quantity) for part_type in ([Part 1], [Part 2], [Part 3])
) as pvt
order by order_id
```

This works for me.

I have ordered the resultset by `order_id` as well; there doesn't appear to be a specific order in your example results but it is mentioned in the question details.

You can see the key is to combine the `PIVOT` with a `SUM` aggregate window function.

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5b6d/3).